# How power is conserved in tapped capacitor impedance matching circuit..?

Tags: impedance-matching

I have recently came across a text of impedance transformation provided by a tapped capacitor arrangement.
Its a rare and unique text explaining the working of tapped capacitor network in terms of conservation of power.
figure 6.31a) is an untapped case when no tapped capacitor is used..fig 6.31b) uses a tapped capacitor network(C1&C2)

The law of power conservation states that..If the magnitude of the power of an individual component in a circuit increases to a certain amount then there should be some compensatory change by the same amount in power of another component to maintain the overall power of the circuit constant.

In case I IL and Vi is constant, in second figure with use of tapped cap. Vi and IL changes which decreases the output current Io and increases the output voltage Vo, hence the latter can be thought of as increase in impedance.

Case 1 Vi and IL constant and power is conserved, whereas in case 2 Vi changes , IL changes which results in increase in Vo and Io,

My query is:-what kind of compensatory change is produced or observed when Vo and Io changes with the use of tapped capacitors, hence increasing the load impedance???

Thanks!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you need to study the Colpitts oscillator to get to grips with this. It's certainly not rare or unique for it. Get a simulator is my advice.

Comment: I use LT spice simulator, but how can I visualise conservation of power with it.

Comment: Power in equals power dissipated in Rs. I wouldn’t call it conservation just an impedance transformer as per many applications in RF circuits.

Comment: Ok.The "external required voltage" also increase whereas output current decreases...is it some kind of balancing force which compensates a change in Vi and IL. I mean to say why did the output voltage increased.

Comment: You need to show how you are driving the circuit so I can understand your question. Or just use LTSpice to calculate input and output power.

Comment: Let me explain so that you can understand my point..In fig 6.31a) IL and Vi is constant and in fig 6.31b) due to presence of two capacitors IL and Vi changes hence reducing the the output current Io and increasing the externally required voltage (i.e output voltage Vo) underlined. So my question is why this external voltage increases which is technically equal to increase in impedance...Is it a compensatory change just in order to conserve power in circuit..??

Comment: It's just a basic impedance convertor circuit. Pretty standard stuff when you do the math but, it only works at a small range of specific frequencies. I wouldn't call it compensatory change or have some fixation about conservation of power because power can only enter the circuit from the supply source and exit as heat from the resistor.

Comment: I thought in this fashion just because the text says that the internal power of the resonator has to remain the same..in the same way the internal voltage vi has to stay the same increasing the externally required voltage..now what does that mean..

Comment: I think the text was written by someone with problems expressing what they mean. It's a regular impedance transformer used in a variety of circuits and relies on resonance to convert one impedance into a bigger or smaller value at a specific range of frequencies.

Comment: Try to find this paper on the internet: Analysis and Applications of the Capacitive Transformer by Ramon Vargas Patron.